# How to replce the url using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

On clicking hot kyes ctrl+t anywhere from my application it should redirect url to http://localhost:8080/myapp/account/create 
i'm doing it by placing .js file in js folder and including that file in every page. thae content of .js file is

```
    jQuery(document).bind('keypress', 'Ctrl+T',function (evt){ 
    window.location.href =("http://localhost:8080/myapp/account/create");
    return false
 });
```

where myapp is Controller and create is the Action . so i don't want to hard code the entire url insted, whatever the url, only the controller and action should get replaced. so that in production environment i need not to change the url. this is grails application

Comment: Now it works fine.. is there any way to create the url jus by passing controller and action?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you problem is to pass current context path into javascript, is it?

You can remember current context name in your view (in base layout, for example), put it into your `<head>` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.pageContext = '${request.contextPath}';
</script>
```

and then use it from other javascript like:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keypress', 'Ctrl+T',function (evt){ 
    window.location.href = window.pageContext + "/account/create";
    return false
});
```

Or, if you need to generate full path to your controller+action you have to use:

```
<g:createLink controller="account" action="create" />
```

see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html for more information

Comment: window.pageContex == /myapp(it returns)  What about localhost:8080?

Comment: it also stored in context, and inside grailsApplication